# How to add reference of WCF service to .Net CF 2.0 application?

Tags: c#, asmx, wcf

The .net CF 2.0 application does not understand the WCF proxy. So, it neds to be converted to ASMX proxy first and then to be added as reference to .net CF 2.0 application.
But this is in theory. Need to know the exact steps of how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good article on how to do it with the netcfsvcutil.exe.

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WCF/netcfwcf.aspx

Answer (score 0):

In your .net CF 2.0 project, you should be able to add a reference the WSDL for the WCF-based service. Having done that, the project should build a .net CF 2.0-compatible proxy.